# Flash Message in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3 and i want to show a message to user when user singup to the website. In my main.blade.php i wrote the following code for getting message on my page

```
     @if(Session::has('message'))
      div class="alert">
      {{Session::has('message')}}
      </div>
      @endif
```

In my controller function i want to redirect user to my home page for this purpose i wrote down following code

```
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message','you have singup successfully please login');
```

Now on my home page a div is coming with respective style but message is not coming in this div.Instead of the message "1" is coming in this div.
Any solution or tutorial will be your best anticipation. 
Regards

Comment: Session::flash('message', 'you have singup successfully please login.'); keep like this and check

Comment: i have to show this message after the user signup.

Comment: pass that in controller based on condition it will come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `session::has()`, the `has` function simply checks if it exists. To use the value in the session use `session::get()`.

This code should serve you well:

`<div class="alert">
   {!! Session::get('message') !!}
</div>`

If you want the message only to be shown once, you could flash the session.

Instead of using `Redirect::to('/')->with('x','y');` 
You can use 
`Session::flash('message', 'This message will be shown once!' );` but you'll have to add that code before you do the redirect and you won't need the `with()` anymore.

For more information about Laravel Sessions have a look at the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

Comment: Thanks @Arnold it work , but it is no disappearing until i refresh the page.

Comment: only after it appeared.

Comment: more presisely i am said , 
how can i set the message time period of the message

Answer (score 1):

```
  Try this code:

   In  Controller:

    if ($x->save()) {
                    return Redirect::route('/')->with('success', 'Added Successfully!!');
                } else {
                    return Redirect::route('/')->with('fail', 'Failed');
                }

    View Page:

    @if(Session::has('success'))
                                      <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('success')}}</div>
                                      @elseif(Session::has('fail'))
                                      <div class="alert alert-danger">{{Session::get('fail')}}</div>
                                      @endif
```

Comment: Thanks @Soniya  i have tried and it is perfectly working.

Comment: Pleasure is mine..@Qadeer_Sipra

Comment: i have rate it up :) @sona